# several error for pvcreate and lvcreate

Tags: linux, lvm

I am getting the following error

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpathd
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/mpathd at 0 length 512.
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/mpathd at 0 length 4.
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/mpathd at 4096 length 4.
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/mpathd at 0 length 512.
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/mpathd at 0 length 4.
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/mpathd at 4096 length 4.
```

what should I do to solve this ? how to find what is wrong ?

some info that could be useful

```
ls -l /dev/mapper/mpathb*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Jun  3 06:03 /dev/mapper/mpathb -> ../dm-3
```

and also I added this in a filter (found here https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2423461)

```
/etc/lvm/lvm.conf file

filter = [ "a|/dev/sda|", "a|/dev/mapper/*|" , "r/block/", "r/disk/", "r/sd.*/", "a/.*/" ]
```

it did not work and I got the same error.

I also tried to fdisk it but I got this error

```
fdisk /dev/mapper/mpathd
fdisk: cannot open /dev/mapper/mpathd: Input/output error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries in `/dev/mapper` are LVM logical volumes. That is not possible to create LVM volume on existing LVM volumes.

You can only use physical disks like `/dev/sda` or physical volumes, like `/dev/sda1` to create LVM physical volume.

For example you have 2 disks `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, so the correct syntax:

To initialize disks as a Physical Volume

```
pvcreate /dev/sda
pvcreate /dev/sdb
```

Then you need to create a Volume Group named vg1 for example

```
vgcreate -s 32M vg1 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

Now you can create a 20GB Logical Volume lv1 from some of the free space in vg1

```
lvcreate -n lv1 -L 20G vg1
```

See more details at [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) page

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be of a residual of storage removed
partprobe   will clean /dev/mapper and /dev from the removed storage